# How can I get my selected images to appear in the order that they were selected?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, core-data

In my application users select images from a collection view and those images are saved to core data and when the user goes to another view controller the images appear in that new collection view. The problem that I am having is that the images do not always reappear in the order that they were selected, which they have to. I am trying to get the get the images to appear (localIdentifier) in the order that they were selected (location). What am I doing wrong?

**Detail View Controller**

```
var identifier: [String] = []
var imageIndex: [Int] = []

func retrieveData() {

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EntityTest")
    
    do {
        let result = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            let mimages = data.value(forKey: "image") as! SelectedImages
            for element in mimages.images {
                imageIndex.append(element.location)
                imageIndex.sort(by: <)
                identifier.append(element.localIdentifier)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed")
    }
}
```

**Custom Class**

```
public class SelectedImages: NSObject, NSCoding {
    public var images: [SelectedImage] = []
    enum Key: String {
        case images = "images"
    }
    init(images: [SelectedImage]) {
        self.images = images
    }
    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(images, forKey: Key.images.rawValue)
    }
    public required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let mImages = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Key.images.rawValue) as! [SelectedImage]
        self.init(images: mImages)
    }
}

public class SelectedImage: NSObject, NSCoding {
    public var location: Int = 0
    public var duration: Int = 10
    public var localIdentifier: String = ""
    
    enum Key: String {
        case location = "location"
        case duration = "duration"
        case localIdentifier = "localIdentifier"
    }
    init(location: Int, duration: Int, localIdentifier: String) {
        self.location = location
        self.duration = duration
        self.localIdentifier = localIdentifier
    }
    public override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(location, forKey: Key.location.rawValue)
        aCoder.encode(duration, forKey: Key.duration.rawValue)
        aCoder.encode(localIdentifier, forKey: Key.localIdentifier.rawValue)
    }
    public required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let mlocation = aDecoder.decodeInt32(forKey: Key.location.rawValue)
        let mduration = aDecoder.decodeInt32(forKey: Key.duration.rawValue)
        let mlocalIdentifier = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Key.localIdentifier.rawValue) as! String
        
        self.init(location: Int(mlocation), duration:Int(mduration), localIdentifier:String(mlocalIdentifier))
    }
}
```

**cellForItemAt**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cvCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell

        imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item) as PHAsset,
                                targetSize: CGSize(width:120, height: 120),
                                contentMode: .aspectFill,
                                options: requestOptions,
                                resultHandler: { (image, info) in
                                    cell.imageView.image = image
                                })

        guard let asset = self.fetchResult?[indexPath.item] else {
            return cell
        }
        cell.representedAssetIdentifier = asset.localIdentifier
        imgManager.requestImage(for: asset,
                                targetSize: cell.imageView.frame.size,
                                contentMode: .aspectFill,
                                options: nil) { (image, _) in
            if cell.representedAssetIdentifier == asset.localIdentifier {
                cell.imageView.image = image
            }
        }
        let idx = selectedCells.firstIndex(of: indexPath) ?? -1
        cell.index = idx + 1
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I'm thinking that you need to let us know what you mean by "ordered". Is this by some kind of meta data? By how they are shown in a picker? This matters! Second question - okay, let's say your picker view is ordered like you want, and includes selecting multiple images. Is the order by "picked first" then "picked second", etc.? All this collection view is *is* a picker.

Comment: Actually I am not using image picker because it did not allow me to place an overlay onto the image when the user selected an image. At least not without a third party library (that I am aware of), which I want to avoid as much as possible. I also tried PHPickerViewController but I was not able to present it in a collection view, and since PHPickerViewController is so new I could not find much information on how to do it so I stayed with a simple collection view. As for the order it is a simple Int that is assigned when the user selects the image.

Comment: Okay, now I'm sure I'm missing something. (And I agree, third party libraries are a headache.) I thought your collection view **was** a collection of images, just like both image pickers Apple provides. Are you rolling your own picker as a collection view? If so, then it's not so much an image picker issue as the order of collection view cells selected, right?

Comment: Yes, I am essentially creating my own image picker and putting them into a custom collection view. I am also keeping the count and order of when a user selects an image. I am then sending that information to core data as a custom class that is an array of objects. I added my cellForItemAt to the OP for clarification. The issue is that I cannot call the objects from core data to appear in the order that I want.

Comment: I'm not a CoreData coder unfortunately. (But a pretty decent analyst.) So to understand, you are (a) creating a collection view where (b) a user can select multiple cells and (c) the order of selection is important. There's more... it just happens that the cells are images - and most importantly, you've ascertained that you *are* getting the order of selection correct? And if all this is accurate, the real issue is pulling this selection order correctly out using CoreData?

Comment: Yes your assumptions are correct. I keep looking at it and now I am assuming that the issue is with fetchAssets because it looks like the selections are going into the array correctly but for whatever reason it seems that when fetchAssets runs the images are displayed in an incorrect order. Now I am looking at a possible async issue (just a WAG that is out of desperation).

Comment: You're in over my head. Good luck! Last thought - if you think it's something dealing with async, maybe you could try doing it synchronously. Yeah, this doesn't scale in any way, but it would rule out a few more things. Again, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

libraries you could use:

Objective-C

1. ELCImagePickerController

Swift

1. LimPicker (WhatsApp's image picker)

Comment: This doesn’t seem to answer the question at all.